# Mailcatcher not working in staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rubygems

I was pretty happy with mailtrap (http://mailtrap.io/) until i found out it got slow. Sometimes it doesn't send email or takes long time.

So thought of alternative and moved to mailcatcher (http://mailcatcher.me/).
The issue is, it works fine in development environment but cant made it to work on staging env. Whenever I go for port 1080 to see the mail, path does not finds out.

BTW I am using mailcatcher for my rails app.

Thanks;

[Update]
My mailer setting:
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :host => http://mydomain.com, :port => 1025 }

BTW when I start mailcatcher daemon process. It logs out

```
==> smtp://127.0.0.1:1025
==> http://127.0.0.1:1080
```

Not my actual host, is it the problem ?

Comment: What means "not working"?  Are you getting some error messages?  Are you sending emails in background using some job queue or straight from controller?

Comment: Actually does not finds the path.
Going for mydomain.com:1080 throws path not found.

My mailer setting:
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :host => http://mydomain.com, :port => 1025 }.

BTW when I start mailcatcher daemon process. It logs out
==> smtp://127.0.0.1:1025
==> http://127.0.0.1:1080

Not my actual host, is it the problem ?

Answer (score 20):

By default mailcatcher only runs against the loopback interface (hence the 127.0.0.1 address), so it will only be accessible from the machine it is running on.

You can use the `--ip`, `--smtp-ip`, `--http-ip` options when running mailcatcher to control which ip addresses it binds to.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would say the answer of Frederick is correct.

However for some reason for us this did not work. Mailcatcher refused to listen on the ip-address. To workaround we just proxied all the traffic through `Nginx`. Could also be done with another proxy. Anyways, here is our config:

```
server {
  listen 3020;


  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1080;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

}
```

You can then access your server like this: `myserver.com:3020`

Seems a bit of a hack, but hope this helps.

Comment: Work well! nice!

Answer (score 1):

Well I went back to mailtrap, and its fine now. I had some issue with my app, and because of that mail was not being sent. Its all fine now.

Anyway, thanks guys for trying to help me out.

Happy Programming ;)